# Chrome developer tools - Network - how to filter only POST and PATCH requests?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In the Chrome browser - Chrome developer tools - Network - I can show only POST requests by putting "method:POST" in the Filter search box.
What filter should I use in order to see both PATCH and POST requests?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

The filter option is quite powerful, but it's limited to only using AND (conjunction). So simple workaround would be to use negatives...
For instance, in your case you could create a filter like this:

> -method:GET -method:OPTIONS -method:PUT

This should filter out most of the requests. If you have other offending HTTP verbs you can easily add them.

Comment: Surprisingly... this works with Firefox too! (I am using ver 58).

Comment: this is great, and I'd add a [reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference) here, because there's a bunch of other helpful options. Another hint is: type just `-` in the filter field - and you'll see all the options (remove `-` afterwards though, if you're looking for a "positive" filtering)

Answer (score 38):

Like me, I'm guessing many people came to this thread and don't necessarily need to filter to both POST and PATCH. That said, you can just use the filter like this to filter to POST requests:

On the Network Tab, in the filter box, type in:

```
method:POST
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, you can't filter on multiple HTTP methods, or multiple pre-defined filters in general, such as using both `method` and `domain`.

You also can't mix a pre-defined filter and a normal text based one, as I discovered when answering [How to filter by both text and property in Chrome DevTool's network panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42008959/how-to-filter-by-both-text-and-property-in-chrome-devtools-network-panel/42013782#42013782)

You will have to filter one at a time, or alternatively if there's a lot of requests, you could export the HAR and filter based on the JSON output. I gave an example of parsing the JSON [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41572418/how-to-measure-how-many-tcp-connections-were-made-in-a-page/41578993#41578993) if that helps.

[image: Export HAR]