# How to show only HTTP calls in Chrome Developer tools

Tags: http, google-chrome-devtools

I want to only see HTTP verbs GET and POST in the network pane.

What I have tried is

```
-method:GET -method:POST
```

I read that from [stack over flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42202686/chrome-developer-tools-network-how-to-filter-only-post-and-patch-requests/44496832)

I still do see all of js, json, and image gets.
Is there a better way to set the filters?

Comment: Access to js, json or image is still a "GET" request, that's why you still see them in dev tool.

Comment: understood, any way to filter them out?

Comment: In network panel, you can filter by resource type.

Comment: As mentioned in the original post I am using the filter, the "magic" filter is what I am after

Comment: Ah, then you can use negative filter. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use "[negative filter](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/#filter)" in chrome dev tool to filter all .js, .json and image requests.

The syntax is: `-.png -.jpg -.jpeg -.gif -.json -.js` (separate each negative filter with whitespace). For example, 5 requests are filtered in following screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can filter according to types. For only Fetch/XHR (XMLHttpRequest), open developer tools and just select Fetch/XHR.

Then put method:GET or method:POST in filter area.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're using a negative filter here. If you want to only see POST requests, you can use `method:POST`. This will filter out GET, PUT, and so on.